# wireless NIC and Ubuntu server 17.04

Tags: wireless, server

i recently installed Ubuntu server 17.04 on a custom desktop. i do not have access to an Ethernet cable where i live but i can get wifi, i have wireless nic card installed on my pci X 16 slot on my computer and i also have the cd with the drivers. I have been trying to figure what command to use to install the drivers but i can't find anything online. please help!

Comment: Let's see if we can identify the wireless device first. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`

Answer (score 0):

This link ended weeks of frustration for me:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=571188

I used the WPA (not WPA2, though I'm not sure it matters) instructions. I am working with a 2006-era dell with a Broadcomm driver. The key for me was altering the recommended configuration of wpa_supplicant as follows:

in wpa_supplicant.conf, do everything that link says except:

  `proto=RSN
  pairwise=CCMP
  group=CCMP`

and then use the nl80211 driver, like so:

`sudo wpa_supplicant -Dnl80211 -iyour interface, e.g. wlp4rb1l -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -dd`

Good luck! No idea why this is so easy in desktop Ubuntu, but so very, very difficult with server.

Comment: Can you please list the steps you used, rather than providing only an external link. External links can change, and if it does, your answer would become invalid. Proper steps help anyone else who may have a similar issue. Keep the link, but explaining your work is much more helpful.